# Any idea on how to implement a cusom hashing function in java for any generic object?

Tags: java

Any idea on how to implement a custom hashing function in java  for any generic object? Not using the existing java hash code implementation?

Comment: You can use this: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse will do it for you. Off the source menu.

Comment: It would be good to mention that this feature is supported in almost all IDEs( like Netbeans, MyEclipse, IntelliJ etc )